# Laravel 5.8 - collect method return me undefined index

Tags: laravel, undefined, laravel-collection

I got this array:

[image]

What I want to do next is to make a collection from the array and I write:

```php
$variant_images = collect($p->images);
```

but I got the error:

```
"Undefined index: images"
```

What's bad in my code and how to solve it?

Comment: Please show more code! What is `$p`, how is it initialized? Feel free to checkout [ask] page to see what details are needed.

Comment: $p is the container ... $p mean $product... its an array with 11 elements

Comment: `dd($p->toArray())` ... what does that show

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$p` is array like this

```php
$p = [
  'images' => [
    1, 2, 3, 4
  ]
];
```

you can write

```php
$collection = collect($p);

// access the images
var_dump($collection->get('images'));
```

and the output would be

```php
array:4 [▼
  0 => 1
  1 => 2
  2 => 3
  3 => 4
]
```

Comment: Updated my answer using the `get` method on the collection.